# Spring's RestTemplate bean error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have the following configuration class (used in order to define the RestTemplate bean that can be autowired):

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

But then I'm getting the following error:

```
 The class org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate used in the bean named getRestTemplate is not allowed to use it.
```

What is going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your complete error logs?? BTW its working with me

Comment: why the bean is not public?

Comment: have you tried with this definition: `@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {return builder.build(); }`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work neither

Comment: As you are using SpringBoot, can you define `@Bean(name = "restTemplate")
 public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

  RestTemplate REST_TEMPLATE = builder.build();

  return REST_TEMPLATE;
 }` in the class where you have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation declared

Answer (score 2):

As Amit K Bist said, in the class where you have the notation @SprinBootApplication you should define a bean of type.

> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

I had the same problem, but this fixed it, I hope it helps

```
    package [package];

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan({ [package/s] })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "restTemplate") 
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) { 
        RestTemplate REST_TEMPLATE = builder.build(); return REST_TEMPLATE; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CONFIGURE LIKE THIS:

```
@Configuration
    @ComponentScan(*YOUR PACKAGE NAME*)
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
            converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
            return restTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what difference does this make? why should `@ComponentScan` solve anything?

Comment: Well, you copy+pasted this. My question is how it solves the current problem. `@ComponentScan` does nothing to init the `RestTemplate` bean.

Comment: Thanks for providing info